# Is the illegal nuclear waste at The Westlake Nuclear Landfill a risk to public health?

Tags: environmental-health, radiation, public-health, nuclear-weapons

This Question refers to the 1 of 3 the nuclear landfill sites **in residential/commercial areas** in the St. Louis, MO area. These landfills are a result of the leftovers from the [Manhattan Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_Project)

## Westlake Nuclear Landfill

[Inspired by the new HBO documentary called Atomic Homefront which can be viewed free until Mar 18.](https://www.hbo.com/documentaries/atomic-homefront)

Backstory from the documentary:

> The residents of Bridgeton, Missouri live adjacent to an
> uncontrolled subsurface fire at the Bridgeton-West Lake Landfill,
> which is moving towards illegally dumped radioactive waste. In
> Florissant, Missouri, four miles from the landfill, the neighborhood
> waterway Coldwater Creek meanders through the suburbs for a 14-mile
> stretch.

and,

> Though West Lake Landfill was designated a Superfund site in 1990,
> residents are frustrated to learn that an isolation barrier to keep
> the fire from the radiation waste is merely a proposal, and has not
> even been designed years later. The community fears that nothing will
> keep the fire from reaching the radioactive waste.

---

## The claim I'm challenging is:

From the [EPA which claims](https://www.epa.gov/mo/west-lake-landfill-community-health)

> The scientific data demonstrates that the wastes at the landfill do
> not currently pose an off-site health risk to the surrounding
> community.

And also challenging:

[Ross Knocke Vice president of Republic services claims (the guy who own's the landfill) says:](https://www.citylab.com/equity/2015/10/in-st-louis-fears-rise-as-a-landfill-fire-nears-a-radioactive-waste-site/409846/)

> “Bridgeton Landfill is safe,"

---

Note: What they are referring to as safe is this landfill next to the 8,700 tons of nuclear is a SSE or "Subsurface Smoldering Event" AKA: an underground fire. Which is spreading closer to the 8,700 tons of nuclear waste.

It looks something like this:
[image]

Somehow I missed this updated map from when EPA was pressured to research more.

[image]

---

PS: I'm not affiliated with HBO in any way.

Related question:
[Is the illegal nuclear waste at the Coldwater Creek Nuclear Landfill a risk to public health?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40795/is-the-illegal-nuclear-waste-at-the-coldwater-creek-nuclear-landfill-a-risk-to-p)

Comment: First, it would be better broken up into two questions.  Second, I'd be interested to see what the population distribution looked like for that second map.  Cancer per square mile is a lot less interesting than cancer per population.

Comment: Why is it tagged nuclear-weapons?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - There is a connection, in that the Manhattan project was the one that produced the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs.